# fitbitScraper does not log in

Tags: fitbit

I used to be able to use the fitbitScraper package to access the intra-day setps count and heart rate data for our study. Recently though, the "login" function of the package has stopped working. I receive the following error message after my each attempt to log in:

```
login("myemail@gmail.com", "mypassword", rememberMe = TRUE)
```

Error in login("myemail@gmail.com", "mypassword", rememberMe = TRUE) : 
  login failed

I wonder if anyone has experienced this problem and knows a fix to it.

I have tried re-installing the package, even updating R to its latest version but none of them has helped.

Comment: No solution from me, but the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Fitbit recently updated their API and no longer allows for using web scraping methods. Best to use the direct Fitbit API and the *personal* app setting to access your own data.

[More information can be found here](https://community.fitbit.com/t5/Researcher-Community/Login-to-fitbit-from-R-shut-down-fitbitscraper/m-p/2198481#M18).